# Vis.js nodes don't change size

Tags: reactjs, vis.js

Hello people of Stack Overflow!

I'm using vis.js to create a network at the moment, and I have the following two nodes:

```
const startNode = {
      id: "start",
      shape: "circle",
      size: 1,
      color: { border: "brown", background: "brown" },
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      fixed: true,
    };
const endNode = {
      id: "end",
      shape: "circle",
      size: 500,
      color: { border: "brown", background: "brown" },
      x: 1000,
      y: 0,
      fixed: true,
    };
```

My problem is that whatever number I use for the size of my end node - be it 500 or 1 - it always has the same size as the start node with the size of 1. Let me know if anyone's faced this problem with Vis.js before and has a solution. Much appreciated!

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMRPW.png)